# Import Book content and structure from another drupal website

Tags: importing-exporting, nodes

I am looking to implement an 'Open Government Guide' on my website.

[Here is a link to one of the books that I would like to copy](http://www.rcfp.org/alabama-open-government-guide)

My question is - How do I copy both the Book Content and Book Structure from another Drupal site that I do not have admin access to? Ideally I would be able to do this for all 50 States.

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't got admin access then you'll need to scrape the content. The module [Example Web Scraper](https://drupal.org/project/example_web_scraper) would be a good starting point.

I think [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4384493/how-can-i-ethically-and-legally-scrape-data-from-a-public-web-site) on the ethics of web scraping may also be relevant.